# Display of the correct year of the calendar week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am looking for the exact year of the calendar week:

```
data = {'Date': ['31.12.2022','01.01.2023','02.01.2023','31.12.2023','01.01.2024','02.01.2024','31.12.2024','01.01.2025','02.01.2025']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d.%m.%Y")
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['YearWeek'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%y%V')
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Year_1'] = (df['Date']+pd.to_timedelta(6-df['Date'].dt.weekday, unit='d')).dt.year
df
```

result:

```
    Date     Week   YearWeek Year   Year_1
0   2022-12-31  52  2252    2022    2023
1   2023-01-01  52  2352    2023    2023
2   2023-01-02  1   2301    2023    2023
3   2023-12-31  52  2352    2023    2023
4   2024-01-01  1   2401    2024    2024
5   2024-01-02  1   2401    2024    2024
6   2024-12-31  1   2401    2024    2025
7   2025-01-01  1   2501    2025    2025
8   2025-01-02  1   2501    2025    2025
```

but I need YearWeek 2252 for 2023-01-01 (Row 1) or YearWeek 2501 for 2024-12-31 (Row 6).
What did I wrong?

Comment: year week for `2023-01-01` will be 2301 and for `2024-12-31` should be 2452 right?

Comment: What is your logic for a year week? From the outset, the values shared by Himansu Poddar seem to be correct.

Comment: many thanks meanwile i found the correct aproach for me in  FObersteiner answer

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want ISO year + week output (not the datetime's year), so something like this should work:

```py
df['WeekYear'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week

df['YW'] = df['WeekYear'].astype(str).str[2:] + df['Week'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)

df[['Date', 'YW']]

        Date    YW
0 2022-12-31  2252
1 2023-01-01  2252
2 2023-01-02  2301
3 2023-12-31  2352
4 2024-01-01  2401
5 2024-01-02  2401
6 2024-12-31  2501
7 2025-01-01  2501
8 2025-01-02  2501
```

Comment: many thanks FObersteiner ... this is exactly what I'm looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

The point is, ISO 8601 specifies that the week containing the first Thursday of the year is the first week of the year, and is numbered as week 1. This is also known as European week numbering.

So depending on the year, YYYY-01-01 may be included in week 1 of year YYYY, or in week 52 (or possibly 53!) of year YYYY-1. And YYYY-12-31 may be in week 1 of year YYYY+1.